# Preg match - removing strange characters from an email address

Tags: php, preg-replace

could some suggest how using some form of preg_replace or similar function I can remove the dot just before the at sign within this email address -

```
a.d.q.s.@webdomin.co.uk
```

I have a system for sending emails but unfortunately due to the way the client collates data there is a number of incorrect email addresses added to their csv.

I use the SwiftMailer class and it isn't liking some of the emails within an array that are being passed from a csv.

Comment: most probably not a good idea.. what if the email does have a dot?

Comment: What exactly are "strange" characters? Read: http://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this simple regex:

```
preg_replace('/\.\@/','@',$emailAddress);
```

Would this fit your needs or do you need something more complex?

Comment: Why are you escaping the `@` (which needs not to be escaped) but not the `.` (which actually does)?

Comment: Sorry I mean the last dot from them email address - the swiftMailer class I am using gives a error that states it doesn't match some RFC universal email standard & stops the script.

Comment: 'g' is not a preg_match [modifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)

Comment: @NullUserException I'm escaping the . (\.)? I wasn't sure about the @. I removed the g modifier, which was incorrect.

Comment: @Boo M42 added the `\.`, your [original post](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/7309005/1) didn't have it.

Comment: @NullUserException Oh, that's weird, because i definitly thought about it and I know I have to escape it. No matter what, I'm sorry :) Gaz, can you tell if this is what you need or if I got your question wrong.

Comment: I think the OP doesn't really understand what s/he wants.